# Redux state - difference between DevTools and Redux store

Tags: reactjs, redux, state

I am using a selector to get parts of the application state, as advised by the Redux documentation.

However, I am experiencing a slight difficulty.

I update a part of the state, like this:
state->query->(set)origin

when i try to access this state part using a selector, like:

```
const selectQuery = (state) => state.get('query')
```

, what I actually get is a litle bit different (and harder to manage) than I was expecting.

I was expecting to have an object with query as a key, than inside that another object with origin as a key, and finaly its value.
This is also what i see on the redux devtools, image below.

[image]

However, my actual state is different.
What I actually have is:
query (map object) with a "_root" key, which has an "entries" key, which has an "array" key, with two objects "origin" and the value of it. image below.

[image]

Is this difference somehow normal?
If i want to acces the origin value, do i really need to do something like:

```
const selectquery = (state) => state.query._root.entries.array[1]
```

Comment: Hi @Rafael, `query` is an instance of a `Map` as can be seen. You can readily access `origin` as follow: ```const selectOriginQuery = (state) => state.get('query').get('origin')```

Comment: yeah, you are right, my question was confusing, i was not directly accessing origin, but state, and all that "proto" stuff around it made it confusing. especialy given that "origin" and "Porto" were not a key, value pair, but instead elements of an array